# Unable to use the provided expo tunnel url on my physical device

Tags: react-native, expo, eas, expo-go

Since the expo dev tools UI has been deprecated, I am unable to figure out a way to publish new updates of my app to be tested on Expo Go. I tried using tunneling `expo start --tunnel` but the url that expo provides only returns a json object on my device(chrome app). I need help figure out how I can have someone else in a different location test the application in dev mode. I can't use EAS Build because it requires me to have a paid apple developer account. I just want to be able to publish to expo go, would appreciate any help or input.

Tried EAS Build but it requires me to have a paid apple developer account and it seems to create a production build.